# how to create mmjmenu using php api?

Tags: php

I want to add product using MMJMenu api from my php application.

we can easily get MMJMenu products using it's api to our application but how to create product using api

Here using this code i can get product...

```
<?php
require 'API/Mmjmenu.php';
$client = new Mmjmenu('JHDGFDS46JSsdf654FSJHDSH');

$menuItems      = $client->menuItems();
$menuItems      = json_decode($menuItems, true);

foreach($menuItems['menu_items'] as $item)
{
    echo $item['name'];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MMJMenu API is read-only, so there is currently no option to create new menu items through the API.

Comment: Are you sure it's not possible in MMJMenu? or it is possible to create menu in weedmaps using MMJMenu api or not ?

Comment: Yes I am sure it's not possible to create menu items through the MMJMenu API.

It is possible to create menu items in Weedmaps through MMJMenu if you enter your Weedmaps API key into your MMJMenu account, and enable syncing to Weedmaps.

Comment: ok thanks... for Weedmaps i need to use this api or any other api is available and if you done this kind of work then provide some code example for creating weedmaps menu...

Comment: The MMJMenu to Weedmaps API is a private API which means you will not be able to access it yourself. Its setup to allow both systems to communicate with each other, privately, through API keys.

That's why you need to login to Weedmaps, get your Weedmaps API key, and then add it to your MMJMenu account. Then MMJMenu will 'have access' to post menu items to your Weedmaps account.

Obviously this means when you add menu items in MMJMenu, they will sync over to Weedmaps automatically. This also means you will NOT be able to utilize that private API in your own code.

Comment: thanks once again... i already done this process and list the products to my site but there is no any methods in api file for creating products through MMJMenu API........if you have any code like these than please share with me..